# v2- Clustering Algorithms

Tags: cluster-analysis, sigma.js

I want to cluster my sigma nodes based on importance or region(sigma graph is bound to a background Leaflet).
For example, would love to display only 1 node for a node group.

E.g: https://deck.gl/examples/icon-layer/

Anybody got an idea which algorithm to use and how to go about it implementing it in sigmajs v2?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the community for each node, you should be able to create a new graph, with one node per community where their positions is the barycenter of the nodes in the community